# Spring boot microservices - retrieving data from DB

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-feign

I'm new in Microservices architecture and I'm trying to build a simple projects with two spring boot microservices, eureka as service discovery and spring cloud for an API Gateway.
UserService and OrderService are connected to different MySQL schema and my question is, how to retrieve data from orders_table by calling rest method through the client and passing the user id ? I have a dashboard where I have to show all the orders made by the logged user.

The client project is a Spring Boot app with Web and RestTemplate dependencies.

Below the table struture:

users_table:
   id,
   name,
   lastName

orders_table:
   id,
   description,
   user_id

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1: Call user service from the dashboard application to retrieve the user_id, then make a second call from the dashboard application to get the orders for the user_id.

Option 2: Have a third service which will act as an aggregator. From the dashboard application call the aggregator, which in turn will first fetch the user_id  from the user service and then the associated orders from the orders service.

Comment: I'll adopt the option 1 approach on Spring MVC client project using RestTemplate. Thanks for your time

Comment: Hi Ravi, what about FeignCient ? I red that is usefull when a microservice needs to call another one..Should I have to integrate it ?
I can perform a rest call to a dashboard-service, from mvc client, and this service will call user-service and order-servide through feign client..Let me know if you already used it. Thank you

Comment: I am aware of it, but did not use it. These days I am primarily using WebFlux. So, I am making Rest calls with the async, non blocking WebClinet.

Answer (score 1):

You can use JPA repository to fetch the required data. You can define Entity models for you tables. JPA repository will give you CRUD operations out of the box which you can utilise to fetch data with your query.

Reference Link : https://www.baeldung.com/the-persistence-layer-with-spring-data-jpa

Comment: Sorry but I didn't get your point.. Of course with JPA I will be able to fetch the required data in case of a single database with n tables. In this case, I have two microservices connected to different schemas.

Comment: You should expose this as an API in OrderService (Controller -> Service -> DTO -> Querying Order table using JPA Repository).

Comment: My order service is connected only to the order database,and user service is connected only to user database.

Comment: Your order table must have a reference key for the user. Order row should be created for a particular user. I think this question falls under data modelling.